# How do I stop a print statement in a for loop from printing repeatedly if the loop needs to continue running?

Tags: python, for-loop

The circumstances in my code make it as such that even after looking for a while, I couldn't find an applicable answer. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
value = int(input())
list = [5,10,15,20]

for i in list:
    if i == value:
        print("Value is in list.")
        break
    else:
        print("Value is not in list.")
```

If I were to input 15, the code would print

"Value is not in list.
Value is not in list.
Value is in list."

but I only want it to print "Value is in list." one time if it is in the list and print "Value is not in list." one time if it is not. I have to keep the for loop and the if/else statements. As far as I can tell, I can't use `break` in the else without ending the loop entirely. What do I do?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a flag, the flag is False by default, and if you find the value, you set the flag to True.

After the `for` iteration finish, you can check the flag variable value to realize whether the value is on the list or not

```
value = int(input())
list = [5,10,15,20]

found = False
for i in list:
    if i == value:
        found = True
        break

if found:
    print("Value is in list.")
else:
    print("Value is not in list.")
```

This is a way to just update your algorithm and make it work, otherwise you can just use `if value in list` to check if the element is in your list

Answer (score 5):

This may not be your goal, but couldn't you just check if the value exists in the list one time, rather than iterating?

```
value = int(input())
_list = [5,10,15,20]

if value in _list:
    print("Value is in list.")
else:
    print("Value is not in list.")
```

Comment: Agreed, I think this is the best approach.

Comment: @LPR it's certainly more Pythonic to not iterate here, but it's possible that OP's use-case/assignment/etc. may be to flag via iteration.

Comment: Yes, I've tested this but one of the requirements of my program is to use a for loop, specifically. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a boolean.

```
value = int(input())
list = [5,10,15,20]
firstTime = True
for i in list:
    if i == value and firstTime == True:
        print("Value is in list.")
        firstTime = False
    else:
        if firstTime == True
            print("Value is not in list.")
            firstTime = False
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it prints "Value is not in list" for any input except for 5.

Comment: That's not my problem. I showed you what I asked. Though being a nice person i'll figure out why and edit my post.

Comment: Actually just realized, the top answer provides an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might move that to a function, which can be terminated at any time.

```
def isin(val):  
    list_ = [5, 10, 15, 20]  
    for i in list_:  
        if val == i:  
            print("Value in list")  
            return  
    print("Value not in list")      


isin( int(input()) )
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest in terms of having to iterate over the list rather than using a flag.

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare a boolean variable as follows:

```
value = int(input())
list = [5,10,15,20]
avail=False

for i in list:
    if i == value:
        avail=True
        break  
        
if avail:
    print('Value in List')
else:
    print('Value not in List')
```

A more simpler way is using the `in` keyword as follows:

```
value = int(input())
list = [5,10,15,20]

if value in list:
    print('Value In list')
else:
    print('Value Not in list')
```